# Featured tab shows heavily downvoted questions

Tags: discussion, downvotes, user-interface

Is the Featured tab meant to show any and all questions with a bounty? I have seen heavily downvoted questions appear time and again in that tab. For example:

[image: Downvoted + Featured]

This is an off-topic question with 10 DVs, yet it still appeared at the top of the Featured page. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how it works. If you hover over the tab, it will tell you "Questions with open bounties" - that is the only criteria for a question to appear there, having an open bounty.

Comment: Ah I see it now. Thanks for the clarification. But perhaps SO should consider renaming that tab.